# How does \w work?

Tags: regex, perl

In `perl` programming, `\w` is a kind of regular expression.

What I would like to know is how does it match? Whether it matches a character or a word,same question to `\w+`?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes

Comment: also, take a look at [here](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4), basics

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the manual.

Answer (score 7):

`\w` is a [shorthand character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Could be said to be the equivalent to the character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. It might be worth pointing out that it will match any 1 character from the ranges specified in the character class.

And since the operator `+` is used to mean 1 or more times, `\w+` means any character within the range mentioned earlier, at least one time.

Hence, `\w+` can match a single character (letter, number or underscore), a word containing any of letters, numbers and/or underscores.

If you want to be strict about `\w`, it matches these characters (and maybe more). The image below is found in the link I posted above.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`\w` means "any letter, digit or the underscore".

Many think it's equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but it is **not**. It is that as well as every Unicode character that is a letter or digit, including non-Latin characters such as Chinese, Arabic, etc.

Comment: I think about using `Unicode` in `perl` that guy could drown us with questions.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` is a *character class* which represent any alpha-numeric symbol, i.e. that means that `\w` is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` combination. `+` is a *quantifier* which means repetition *at least once* of symbol (or group) which was preceded by it. Also note, that `\W` (uppercase) is negative form of `\w` (lowercase) which means *all, except any symbol from* alpha-numeric class, i.e. that means `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

`\s` is *character class* for whitespace characters, i.e. `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`

`\S` is, acordingly, negation form: `[^ \t\n\r\f\v]`

**Quantifiers:**

`+` means repeat more or once

`*` means repeat how much possible (even zero times)

`?` means repeat just one time or zero

Comment: so if the test string like "this is a test.", \w matches 't',and \w+ matches 'this',right?

Comment: nope, for `\t` and `\n` there is `\s` class

Comment: Careful about your definition about what `\w` matches: The Unicode nazis will get you :-)

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right :) it depends on `LOCALE` heavily, for details the reference is your guide.